# Cannot find ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

I upgraded my test dependencies for my play project and now I get this problem:

```scala
object scalacheck is not a member of package org.scalatestplus
[error] import org.scalatestplus.scalacheck.ScalaCheckDrivenPropertyChecks
```

These are my test dependencies:

```scala
"org.scalatest"              %% "scalatest"                 % "3.2.3"          % Test,
"org.scalamock"              %% "scalamock"                 % "4.2.0"          % "test",
"com.github.alexarchambault" %% "scalacheck-shapeless_1.14" % "1.2.1"          % "test",
"org.scalatestplus.play"     %% "scalatestplus-play"        % "3.1.2"          % "test, it",
```

Do I have some incompatible versioning going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the right dependency:

```
"org.scalatestplus" %% "scalacheck-1-15" % "3.2.3.0"
```

Since you are using scalatest version 3.2.3, you should use scalacheck version 3.2.3.X, for compatability.

[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatestplus/scalacheck-1-15_2.13) is its maven location, and [this](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatestplus-scalacheck) is its github repo.

- Scala 2.13 Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/y7gzz1L3SuWPazRjhJGNPg).
- Scala 2.12 Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/S6jQNMyXQzmJoOlqSUhQVQ).

Comment: I got it working with this:  "org.scalatestplus"          %% "scalacheck-1-14"           % "3.2.0.0"        % Test,

Comment: @Mojo Please note that `scalacheck-1-14` is older than `scalacheck-1-15` as I suggested. So if you are already adding a new dependency, taking the latest is better. Since you are using `scalatest` version `3.2.3` you should use the `scalacheck` version starts with `3.2.3.x` for compatability. Therefore I understand that what you did solve your issue, but I think you should use my suggestion.

Comment: But I think for scala 2.12 I cannot use scalacheck-1.15. When I tried it could not resolve that dependency